# Creating a function that can return a list of controls with specific information in the control Tag

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am a newbie and I  am trying to get a list of names all the controls that have certain text in the tag field. The controls appear in a form and appear by themselves, on panels, and on tabs.  Irrespective of where they sit is their a way to get a list of all the controls using something similar to LINQ and then I can recursive through it. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `List <Control>`. Then use `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsByTag(Control container, string tag)
{
    var ctrls = container.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return ctrls.SelectMany(c => GetControlsByTag(c, tag)).Concat(ctrls.Where(c => c.Tag != null && c.Tag.ToString().Equals(tag)));
}
```

From any caller:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var controls = GetControlsByTag(this, "Tag_text_To_Find");
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Is there a way to change it to allow an array or list of tags into the query?

Comment: @Robertp Such as? Give an example of that list and the expected output.

Comment: tag = (frm, con) etc.  What I am trying to do is build a list of all the controls so it doesnt repopulate every time.  I would have the routine run one time when the form loads and build the control list based on what information I need on the form.  I build my main form with both the firm and contact information.  So if I could build a list that would allow me to run the routine once to build the list of controls on both frm and con it would be much faster.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: My real goal eventually is to marry up the control with the database field that has the data in it.  For instance i have a control called frmAddress which comes from the table firm.  I also have another control called conAssistant which is the contacts assistant and resides in the Contact table.  I have an Infragistics Grid which I sync to and get the selected row and recurse through all the items in my list and assign the values to the textbox or other control.

Comment: This is what I get when I look up frm and con -> conAssistant, conExt, conFax, conPhone, conRefferedBy, conSalutation, frmAddress, frmBuildingName, frmCity, frmPhone

Comment: @Robertp This is a recursive function which returns ALL the child controls of the passed container, whether it is a Form, Panel, GroupBox or any other container control. Note that, if the passed container also contains other container controls which also contains child controls, the function will get them as well. That's what a recrusive function means. If you need to create a `List<Control>` to list controls from different forms, then you could create a global variable of list of control type, call the function for each form, and add the returned controls to the list.

Comment: @Robertp You can post a new question along with the relevant code and what are you trying to achieve to get more help.